# java.util.ConcurrentModificationException, how to avoid

Tags: java, arraylist

Below is the code:- can you please let me know why it it throwing exception and how to avoid that, thanks for ur help..

```
public Collection getBeansFilteredByAuthorityAndApproach(ITaskContext context)throws CEAppException

{ Collection regApprAuthMapColl = this.getRegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap(context);//Collection of All approach combos

Collection finalAuthApprMapColl = new ArrayList();

ParameterSet pSets = context.getExecutionThread().getParameterSet();

//<RuntimeParameterSet> or list of <RuntimeParameters>

ArrayList apAR =pSets.getRuntimeParameterSet().getRuntimeParametersList();

int apSize = apAR.size() ;

for (int j = 0; j < apSize; j++)

{//1

//Individual <RuntimeParameterSet> or list of <RuntimeParameters>

RuntimeParameters rps = (RuntimeParameters) apAR.get(j);

if (Constants.CLONE_TYPE.equalsIgnoreCase(rps.getType())) //TODO :check if it required or not

{//2

//obtain a list of <RuntimeParameter> or indiviual <RuntimeParameters>

ArrayList rtParams = rps.getRuntimeParameterList();

int rtSize = rtParams.size();

for (int k = 0; k < rtSize; k++)

{//3 FOR EACH RUNTIME PARAMETER , i.e Approach & Authority

//Individual <RuntimeParameter>

Integer inputAuthority = null;

Integer inputApproach = null;

RuntimeParameter rtp = (RuntimeParameter) rtParams.get(k);

logger.debug("========== RuntimeParameter rtp="+rtp);

if (Constants.REGAUTHORITY.equals(rtp.getName()))

{

Integer regAuthority = ReferenceData.getRegAuthority(context,rtp.getValue());

inputAuthority = regAuthority;

} else if (Constants.REGAPPROACH.equals(rtp.getName()))

{

Integer regApproach = ReferenceData.getRegApproach(context,rtp.getValue()) ;

inputApproach = regApproach;

}

//FOR EACH RUNTIME PARAMETER FILTER THE COLLECTIONS

　

//FILTERING DATA

logger.debug("inputApproach :"+inputApproach);

logger.debug("inputAuthority :"+inputAuthority);

if(inputApproach == null)// if APPROACH IS NOT specified in the notification

{

if( inputAuthority == null)// if AUTHORITY IS NOT specified & APPROACH IS NOT specified

{ //Then run for all auhorities and approaches

finalAuthApprMapColl = regApprAuthMapColl;//returning all possible beans

}//end of if

else// if AUTHORITY IS specified & APPROACH IS NOT specified

{ //Then for the given authority, run for all approaches: B1,STD,IRB,AIRB

for (Iterator itr = regApprAuthMapColl.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)

{//looping through all possible values to select

RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap raaMap = (RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap)itr.next();

Integer fullAuthorityId = raaMap.getRegulatoryAuthorityId();

if(inputAuthority.intValue() == fullAuthorityId.intValue())// for a given authority

{

finalAuthApprMapColl.add(raaMap);//returning a list of all approaches for a given authority

}

}//end of for loop

}//end of else

}//end of if approach is null

else//if APPROACH IS specified in the notification

{

if(inputAuthority == null)// if AUTHORITY IS NOT specified && APPROACH IS specified

{//Then for the given approach, run for all authorities: FSA,EBK,BIS

for (Iterator itr = regApprAuthMapColl.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)

{//looping through all possible combos to select

RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap raaMap = (RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap)itr.next();

Integer fullApproachId = raaMap.getRegulatoryApproachId();

if(inputApproach.intValue() == fullApproachId.intValue())// for a given approach

{

finalAuthApprMapColl.add(raaMap);//returning a list of all authorities for a given approach

}

} //end of for loop

}//end of if

else// if AUTHORITY IS specified & APPROACH IS specified

{

for (Iterator itr = regApprAuthMapColl.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)

{//looping through all possible combos to select

RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap raaMap = (RegulatoryAuthorityApproachMap)itr.next();

Integer fullApproachId = raaMap.getRegulatoryApproachId();

Integer fullAuthorityId = raaMap.getRegulatoryAuthorityId();

if((inputApproach.intValue() == fullApproachId.intValue()) && (inputAuthority.intValue() == fullAuthorityId.intValue()))// for a given approach

{

finalAuthApprMapColl.add(raaMap);//returning a list of all authorities for a given approach

}

} //end of for loop

}

}//end of else

}//3

}//2

}//1

if(finalAuthApprMapColl.size() == 0){throw new CEAppException("The Authority/Approach mapping is null"); }

else

return finalAuthApprMapColl;

}//end of method
```

Comment: For future questions, I suggest looking at the [editing help page](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) and making your code readable. You should also consider making the code sample simpler, most of it can't be relevant to triggering a `ConcurrentModificationException`. (You'd probably find the problem while isolating it this way.)

Comment: Paste your entire code here and hope that someone wades through it, debugs it and gives an answer - learn nothing and repeat. I would be happier if the question would have been as to why a concurrent modification exception is thrown but again the javadocs are clear. So if you need a hint, look at the code to find where your modifying the collection structurally without using it's iterator.

Comment: Also, at the very least, point out on which line the `ConcurrentModificationException` occurs. There are five loops in your code sample.

Comment: Unreadable. Please get rid of all the blank lines and indent it properly.

Answer (score 1):

Your code is very unclear, but from what I can work out, you're using an iterator over a given collection:

```
for(Iterator itr = regApprAuthMapColl.iterator(); itr.hasNext();)
```

In this case, the collection is `regApprAuthMapColl`. However, you're also modifying the collection while you're iterating over it, in your for loop you have the following:

```
finalAuthApprMapColl.add(raaMap);
```

This isn't allowed - you can't modify a collection at the same time as iterating over it, and is probably where the exception is thrown.